# Get element in another xaml page in MVVM enviroment

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a mainpage.xaml with this progressbar in :

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="DataLoading" Height="10" Margin="0,-14,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

Now i need to get this progressbar's visibility to collapse after the webservice has been called? where would i go to get it? please help i am VERY new to mvvm and windowsphone dev? and please tell me what more code youneed to give me an answer thanks
1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a bool property `IsDataLoading` to your ViewModel. Bind its value to the [Visibilty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of your `ProgressBar` using the [BooleanToVisibiltyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx). Set the `IsDataLoading` property to true and false according to your webservice state.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="bool2VisConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsDataLoading, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Helo thank for quick response, please give me a quick example of the syntax, cause i have a bool called IsDataLoaded, how would i bind the vis property to this bool? i have never even heard of BooleanToVisibilityConverter

Comment: I have updated the answer with a question, please not that you have to invert the logic of your property or you have to write your own converter.

Comment: awesome! yes it works!, just made a few extra changes, to make mine work! but this basic idea was the one :D thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel:

```
        private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBusy;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isBusy)
                return;
            _isBusy = value;
            DispatcherService.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy);
            });
        }
    }
```

The Progressbar in the view:

```
 <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
```